# Javascript querySelector for select element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to both programmatically get, and programmatically set the innerHTML of the selected value from a select-element in plain Javascript. This is my code:

```
const select = document.querySelector("#myDiv select"); 
console.log(select.selectedOptions[0].option.innerHTML);
```

If I write console.log(select.selectedOptions), I get the following:

[image]

It's the innerHTML inside option that I want to reach and edit, but I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'option' of undefined
```

I did not find much about this online, hence me asking here. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: may I see the detail inside `0: option`?

Comment: `selectedOptions` contains option elements. And it doesn't have options property. Use `selectedOptions[0].innerText`

Answer (score 1):

`select.selectedOptions[0]` returns the actual `option` element itself, so you can get and set `innerHTML` from that directly.

Also make sure you set a `selected` on an option so that something is selected by default and `select.selectedOptions` is never empty.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#myDiv select"); 
console.log("Initial:", select.selectedOptions[0].innerHTML);

const button = document.getElementById('toggle'),
      newText = document.getElementById('newText');
      
button.addEventListener('click', () => select.selectedOptions[0].innerHTML = newText.value);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="option_a" selected>Option A</option>
    <option value="option_b">Option B</option>
  </select><br>
  <input id="newText" type="text" placeholder="Enter text here..."></input>
  <button id="toggle">Change</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

You do not need the .option after selectedOptions[0]

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#myDiv select"); 
console.log(select.selectedOptions[0].textContent); // or .text
// alternative
console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent);
// setting the text:
select.selectedOptions[0].text = "Number one"
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<select>
<option value="1">one</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `option` before innerHTML. Follow the code.

```
const select = document.querySelector("#myDiv select"); 
const optionSelected = select.selectedOptions[0]; 
console.log(optionSelected); 
optionSelected.innerHTML = 'New Demo'
```

**strong text**

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/wvMGjZw)

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined :/

Comment: Not very clear if you changed anything when you set the first value to the same it already is. Anyway I already answered a while ago

Comment: @JensOlsson When do you want to change the option label?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the selected option using a css selector and read its `textContent`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#myDiv select option:checked").textContent);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <select>
    <option value="1">one</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null... don't really understand why

Comment: "don't really understand why" ... That makes two of us. Tested the snippet in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-liner using the :checked pseudo-class in JavaScript to get either the selected text or value.  Here we are assuming we have a select with id="searchList".

```
const selected = document.querySelector('#searchList :checked');//returns selected node
console.log(selected.innerText);//get the selected option text
console.log(selected.value);//get the selected option value
```

Verifying that this indeed works for selected options in select elements, here's the official documentation:

*The :checked CSS pseudo-class selector represents any radio (), checkbox (), or option ( in a ) element that is checked or toggled to an on state.*

[:checked MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)